# Javascript async function gets correct data from API, but only returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript

I looked a bit on the web and couldn't find a good answer to my question, so I'll ask it to you guys.

I have an async function, that gets true/false data from an API, I am able to print the value that I got from the API, but when I return that value, I get an "Undefined" instead.
I feel like the problem is in the way that I return that variable, but like I said I haven't been able to find an answer, so if someone know how to that would be wonderful.

Here is the function:

```
const CheckSource = async function(AttId, symbolId){

//creates the get parameters
    var SourceGetParams = Helper.returnGetOptions(`SignalValues/${symbolId}/${AttId}`);

//send the get request and waits for responce
    await Helper.sendRequest(SourceGetParams).then((res, body) => {

//parses the response, prints the correct value, but returns "undefined"
        var response_body = JSON.parse(res.body);
        var value = response_body.API_Signals[0].RawValue
        console.log(value);
        return Promise.resolve(value);

//error handling
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('error sending source get request:', error);
        return Promise.reject('There was an error with the fusion request.');
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Source sendRequest promise error:', error);
        return Promise.reject('There was an internal error sending the request.');
    }); }
```

I have tried to use different methods to return the value (such as 'return value;') but I get the same result.

Here is how I call the function:

```
CheckSource(<Att_ID string here>, <Symbol_ID string here>).then((data)=>{
    console.log(data)
});
```

I know this is a question that is often asked, and I tried many of the other answers found here, but got no results.

The answer I get is this:

```
False //(this is the expected output from the conslole.log() in the async function)

undefined //(this is the console.log() after I called the function)
```

I really appreciate all of you.

Comment: Your `CheckSource` function isn't returning anything, try returning the result instead of just `await`ing it

Comment: You're awaiting a request, and still using `then` and `catch`.  With async/await it's try/catch. Does `sendRequest` return a promise? Based on the err callback I don't think it does.

Comment: Replace the `await` keyword with the `return` keyword and it will work. There's other problems with your code but this single change will make it work

Answer (score -1):

What I can see in your code is, the function check source is returning a resolved promise from inside of another function and when you are calling it, you are trying to resolve the promise using then and catch. That should not be the case. Try a console log like this

```
console.log(CheckSource());
```

This should print False.